# React matrial ui multiSelect onclose event not working

Tags: reactjs

```js
import React from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120,
    maxWidth: 300,
  },
  chips: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  chip: {
    margin: 2,
  },
  noLabel: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
  },
}));

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
const MenuProps = {
  PaperProps: {
    style: {
      maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
      width: 250,
    },
  },
};

const names = [
  'Oliver Hansen',
  'Van Henry',
  'April Tucker',
  'Ralph Hubbard',
  'Omar Alexander',
  'Carlos Abbott',
  'Miriam Wagner',
  'Bradley Wilkerson',
  'Virginia Andrews',
  'Kelly Snyder',
];

function getStyles(name, personName, theme) {
  return {
    fontWeight:
      personName.indexOf(name) === -1
        ? theme.typography.fontWeightRegular
        : theme.typography.fontWeightMedium,
  };
}

export default function MultipleSelect() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setPersonName(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleChangeMultiple = (event) => {
    const { options } = event.target;
    const value = [];
    for (let i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i += 1) {
      if (options[i].selected) {
        value.push(options[i].value);
      }
    }
    setPersonName(value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-mutiple-name-label">Name</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-mutiple-name-label"
          id="demo-mutiple-name"
          multiple
          value={personName}
          onChange={handleChange}
          input={<Input />}
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
        >
          {names.map((name) => (
            <MenuItem key={name} value={name} style={getStyles(name, personName, theme)}>
              {name}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

I wanted to close the react MultiSelect Menu Once the one item is Selected from the MenuItem. I tried using onClose Event handle in side  but it won't work for me but it keeps changing the state. So please any one can solve this onclose event programatically.The code snippets provided is not working.Thank you